# Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: implicit conversion from 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>? to 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>?' require a temporary

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, swift3, receipt-validation

I have written a method for parsing Receipt of `InAppPurchase` in `Swift2.3` and now I am converting it to `Swift3`. So I am getting this error. Anyone has idea, how to fix this?

[image: Receipt Parsing Error in Swift 3]

Comment: can you add some more code ? like how you r declaring 'p' ?

Comment: var p = (data as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: data.count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
var p: UnsafePointer<UInt8>? = (data as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: data.count)
```

Comment: I have done like this and it worked for me
var p = (data as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: data.count) as UnsafePointer<UInt8>?